# Crawling data from the web then restructure to a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, html, pandas, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I have a code like this:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


URL_TEMPLATES ='https://freemeteo.vn/thoi-tiet/ngoc-ha/history/daily-history/?gid=1572463&station=11376&date={}-{:02d}-{:02d}&language=vietnamese&country=vietnam' #%loc
urls = URL_TEMPLATES.format(2015,1,1)

html_docs = requests.get(urls).text
soups = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)

tables =  soup.find(class_='table-list')
tables
```

Then the results like this:

```
<div class="table-list">
<ul><li><a href="/thoi-tiet/yen-phu/current-weather/location/?gid=1560121&amp;language=vietnamese&amp;country=vietnam" title="Yên Phụ Thời tiết">Yên Phụ</a></li>
<li><a href="/thoi-tiet/huu-tiep/current-weather/location/?gid=1580042&amp;language=vietnamese&amp;country=vietnam" title="Hữu Tiệp Thời tiết">Hữu Tiệp</a></li>
```

Can anyone help me to create `tables` to pandas DataFrame to easy to handle like I can select 'Yên Phụ' string? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse the tables directly with pandas.

```py
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://freemeteo.vn/thoi-tiet/ngoc-ha/history/daily-history/?gid=1572463&station=11376&date={}-{:02d}-{:02d}&language=vietnamese&country=vietnam'
tables = pd.read_html(url)
```

That will give you a list of dataframes. Each table on the page will be one dataframe.

Then you can query a dataframe like:

```py
tables[0].query("Tên == 'Hà Nội'")
```

If you just wanted the cities in `table-list` div:

```py
resp = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text)
table_list = soup.find('div', {'class': 'table-list'})

names, links = [], []

for city in table_list.find_all('a'):
    names.append(city.text)
    links.append(city['href'])
```

To turn the above 2 lists into a dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(names, links), columns=['City', 'Link'])
```